# tapestry5 page to render plain text

Tags: tapestry

I've been looking but can't find the the documentation:

Is there a way to have a page render a response without the wrapping HTML elements and just print whatever is provided in the body of the tml or alternatively whatever is set in MarkupWriter.write during @BeginRender?

I need a page that does some server side processing and returns pure javascript for an external application to request.

If that is impossible, is it possible to expose the tapestry Ioc to a servlet in the same app?

Thanks, p.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry ponzao, but i found a better solution courtesy of Thiago on the tapestry mail list:

```java
public class MyPage
{
    StreamResponse onActivate()
    {
        return new TextStreamResponse("text/plain", "some text");
    }
}
```

this way you don't need to revert to the servlet API and don't need a tml.

adapted from this eg:
http://wiki.apache.org/tapestry/Tapestry5HowToCreateADynamicPDF

Comment: Okay that seems more Tapestryesque.

Comment: Btw select it as the correct answer so this question doesn't remain answerless ;)

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use `MarkupWriter.writeRaw` instead of `MarkupWriter.write` in `@BeginRender`. [Here](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/MarkupWriter.html#writeRaw%28java.lang.String%29) is a link to the API documentation.

**Edit**: If you don't want the document to contain anything else except your text content here is one way to achieve this.

```
@Inject
private Response response

void onActivate() throws IOException {
    PrintWriter writer = response.getPrintWriter("text/html");
    writer.append("foobar");
    writer.close();
}
```

Comment: .. but the .tml would still be rendered, meaning html would still print to the response .. right? from what i can tell, i must have a tml and it must have an <html> element

Comment: Aah okay so let's say you have some code like <script>alert("foo");</script> and you want to so it as such, not wrapped inside <html><head>... Then you could always inject the response and in onActivate get an OutputStream or a PrintWriter and write the response manually, I will add an example.

Comment: thanks that's perfect. FYI you still need to have a .tml file otherwise tapestry throws an exception (internally).

Comment: Glad to help. Okay good to know, I didn't test my solution really extensively :)